# Shuffle Array of integers in solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays

I have an array of integers like this,

```
uint256[] public numberArr = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5,5]
```

What can be the best way to shuffle this array in solidity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function shuffle() external {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < numberArr.length; i++) {
        uint256 n = i + uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp))) % (numberArr.length - i);
        uint256 temp = numberArr[n];
        numberArr[n] = numberArr[i];
        numberArr[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(answering because I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but this is a minor side note to @goodvibration's answer)
in solidity 0.7.0 the "now" keyword has been depreciated, "block.timestamp" should be used instead.

Comment: I edited @goodvibration's post to use "block.timestamp". Just for the record, you should be able to do this as well!

Comment: Oh nice, thanks, I wasn't aware!